# make a link to outside URL amd remove quick access in magento cart

Tags: url, magento, addition, cart

just got handed a magento site to update.  No experience with the cart, so I hope these questions aren't too simplistic.  Did search around a bit and haven't been able to find straightforward answers on either:
1- How do you make a menu item in Magento link to an outside url?  I want the current "shop" link to go to another store site, not the internal cart.
2 - How to remove the quick access shopping cart block info. that links into the cart (my account, shipping bag...).  I could hide it via css but that seems like a bad idea.

Essentially, the client wants to scrap the shopping bit of her cart and continue using magento as a cms.  We want the shop link to go to etsy and the other shopping area access stuff to be removed.  However, I want to leave the actual cart system on the server, in case she changes her mind about using it.  Here's the site: http://www.ledarawlins.com/  thanks for your help!